# Bash if statement fail when filename has whitespace

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

A simple bash script:

```
check_file() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
   echo "File is good"
   #call other functions
  else
   echo "No such file!"
  fi
}
chieck_file "$1"
```

when I call my script passing a path to a file and that file has a whitespace or brackets in name, my shell script fails.
`sh ./bash_script.sh /home/user/foo/foo\ bar\(1\).txt`

Output:
`No such file!`

OS: RHEL8

Comment: It'll fail even with no whitespace. `[-f` is invalid; it __must__ be `[ -f`. Similarly, it needs to be `"$1" ]` with a space, not `"$1"]`

Comment: Also, it's `fi`, not `fe`. Consider making a habit of running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking a question here.

Comment: `chieck_file` ->  `check_file`  *********  `[-f "$1"]` -> `[ -f "$1" ]`

Comment: And `sh` is not `bash`. When you run `sh yourscript` on a modern system, it gets interpreted as a POSIX sh script, not a bash script -- that's a more limited shell with fewer features (even if `sh` is a symlink to bash, it turns off some features when run with that name). On systems that _aren't_ modern (ones that weren't built to honor the 1992 POSIX.2 specification), `sh` may even be Bourne, which is even less compatible with bash than POSIX sh is.

Comment: File is there, I edited the script adding whitespaces around `[]`